# Vacuum Conditions in teaching high school physics

Tags: education, approximations, models

I'd like to know why in high school physics is taught mostly in vacuum conditions instead of terrestrial ones. I don't mean one is more important than the other, but it's just a curiosity about that.

Comment: It's simply that solving problems with air resistance requires considerably more advanced mathematics.

Comment: I don't know if that's even completely true.  The assumption of no air resistance is often used; but vacuum conditions make a lot of other topics very non-intuitive.  From what I remember, the assumptions would change often depending on what aspect of physics we were examining.  If anything, I'd say it uses "simplified terrestrial physics" not "vacuum conditions".  You just assume a lot of things are negligible to focus on the right concept.

Comment: Not true. The atmosphere is not neglected  when teaching about fluids, pressure, barometers and manometers, terminal velocity, effect of wind on the ground velocity of airplanes, aerodynamic lift, etc.

Comment: I think, the OP wants to essentially know, why the Newtonian mechanics is taught, and not the Aristotelian one.

Comment: It's for the same reason why the other half of the questions take place on ice skating rinks or frictionless rollercoasters.

Answer (score 1):

DanielSank and JMac's comments already give the answer: high-school physics is constrained by the amount of time allotted to it and, especially, by the student's previous knowledge of physics and math.

Because of that, more extreme idealizations are usually done, which in mechanics often means neglecting air resistance, but a better description is indeed "simplified terrestrial physics", rather than "vacuum conditions".